# skip on specific folder in FOR loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wrote a batch script that receive a string input and search files with the same string. this loop searching for the file name in the computer, but how do i make it skip on a specific folder so it won't search in there?

```
for %%a in (C D E F G H U W) do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('dir /s /b "%%a:\%filename%"') do (
    ---
    ---
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (
 'dir /s /b "%%a:\%filename%" ^|findstr /v /i /L /c:"%%a:\not in this directory\" '
) do (
```

or

```
 'dir /s /b "%%a:\%filename%" ^|findstr /v /i /L /g:"filename containing directorynames to omit" '
```

Note that both of these methods will skip both the named directory/ies and their subdirectories.

Comment: another thing, can i skip 2 directories like this?

Comment: for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (
 'dir /s /b "%%a:\%filename%" ^|findstr /v /i /L /c:"%%a:\not in this directory\" '
) do (

Comment: for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (
 'dir /s /b "%%a:\%filename%" ^|findstr /v /i /L /c:"%%a:\not in this directory\" ' 'dir /s /b "%%a:\%filename%" ^|findstr /v /i /L /c:"%%a:\not in this directory also\" '
) do (

Comment: can I make it skip only on the exact directory and not the subdirectories?